What part of the auditory system restricts the human hearing frequency range?
It is well known that the human hearing frequency range is always between 20 Hz to 20 kHz.
My question is: what part of the auditory system does this restriction?
I studied the basics of auditory system on my own, specifically the books: Fundamentals of Hearing: An Introduction by W. Yost, and Auditory Neuroscience: Making Sense of Sound by Schnupp, Nelken and King.
I cannot find at what point exactly this frequency restriction happens. Based on what I've read in those books, I think of two possibilities:

It's the tympanic membrane, therefore the frequencies entering the cochlea ARE between this range.

It's the basilar membrane (which has a tonotopy (Schnupp, Sec. 2.1)), however this alternative seems  weird to me, because it means that the tympanic membrane and bones can transmit frequencies above 20kHz, and the frequencies entering the cochlea surpass the hearing range.


I'd appreciate any feedback, thanks!
Edit.
As Narusan pointed out, the cochlear nerves only react to a frequency between 20 Hz to 20 kHz, so we can say that the filtering happens at most in these nerves. My question is if there is a previous part that filters the frequencies before they are picked up by these nerves. Narusan comment made me think of three possibilities:

the tympanic membrane filters tones between 20 Hz to 20 kHz, therefore inside the cochlea there are always sounds between these frequencies.

the tympanic membrane can transmit tones above 20 kHz, therefore inside the cochlea there are sounds above 20 kHz, so the basilar membrane receives frequencies above 20 kHz, this leads to two possibilities: the basilar membrane only reacts to frequencies below 20 kHz and the BM is the part that filters the range, or

the basilar membrane does react to frequencies above 20 kHz and in the end the nerves are the only ones that filter the frequency range


of course, there could be parts that partially filter some frequencies, but I hope the idea of my concern is clear now.

My guess would be that several if not all the components are involved, but I haven't done any research on this so I don't know. It appears you've done some research, but you don't tell us what you found and where you found it. That's a requirement here for questions. A link or two to relevant information, preferably with a relevant quote from that source would be helpful to your question. For example, in #2 you cite some claims of fact. Where did you get those claims?

@CareyGregory Sorry, I'm going to edit my question in order to acknowledge my sources

As you mentioned the concept of tonotopy: Every neuron inside the cochlear nerve corresponds to a certain range of frequency and we do not have neurons above 20kHz or below 20Hz. This is the easy answer. From what I understood, you are interested whether i.e. the basilar membrane of the cochlea is "longer" and there is a part that vibrates at frequencies > 20kHz but no neurons pick up the signal, or whether the tympanic membrane or the basilar membrane act as "low-band pass filters" that cut out all frequencies above 20kHz?

@Narusan I edited my question to adress your comments, and I agree, we can say that the filtering happens at most in the nerves.

The frequency bandwidth of auditory nerve fibers is quite wide, so the cells responding to either 20Hz or 20kHz tones are not going to have those frequencies as their best/optimal frequency, rather that's the far edge of their receptive fields. So I would not name the neurons as the filter, until hearing loss kicks in at which point they definitely are the filter on the higher end; even older children can not hear the highest frequencies that younger children can. There's also no hard cutoff, instead a gradual loss of sensitivity.

@ Bryan Krause Yes a gradual loss of sensitivity. I have a memory of being a 19 year old student. A television on standby in the lecture theatre was emitting a high pitched noise that most students found quite distracting. We had to tell the  approximately 40 year old lecturer about the noise as he was unable to hear it. He turned it off for us, of course.
